# Why would the following download operation run at 1/10 the speed in Jython as it does in Python?

Tags: python, download, jython

I have the following code which I am running under in python and again in jython:

```
import urllib2
import time
clock = time.clock()

def dlTest():
    global clock
    url = "http://##.##.##.##/EXACTADDRESSREDACTED/file.extension"
    print 'downloading update from: ' + url
    _ = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    print 'finished in ' + str(time.clock() - clock)
    clock = time.clock()

dlTest()
```

I was surprised to find that, despite many repeated tests jython takes almost 10 seconds to perform this download, while Python takes only 1/2 a second. Any thoughts?

I'm using Python 2.7 and jython 2.5.3, the file I'm downloading is 40MB and arrives intact in both downloads. I'm simply not saving it on disk in the code above as I was trying to keep the example uncluttered. Tests perform the same both when writing to disk as not. The download is occurring over a local connection, not over an internet connection, and the speed achieved in python is the expected speed.

Further testing has shown that Jython seems to be taking longer to begin the download after execution starts (4 seconds, instead of .06), as well as performing the actual download more slowly (5 seconds, instead of .5).

Comment: Ten seconds? Sounds like *someone's* doing a reverse DNS lookup, which is failing...

Comment: Just set up a test to check for that possibility, @kindall. Doesn't appear to be the case. The time between when the file first appears on the disk and when the download completes is still several seconds. The actual rate of download is indeed slower, not just the execution time.

Comment: There's a bunch of stuff in http://wiki.python.org/jython/NewSocketModule#Differences_between_cpython_and_jython about socket differences between cython and Jython. One thing that jumps out at me is that Jython might be attempting IPV6 which is enabled at least with linklocal addresses on pretty much everything these days - but if it's trying to route to the internet that can cause some problems. When Python.org started responding with IPV6 addresses I had terrible delays while it kept trying to connect via IPV6 and ultimately falling back to IPV4.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but according to the page you linked that error is specific to implementations of Jython on older versions of the JVM.